# Svg fill center of path

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this Svg with a path:

```html
    <svg width="29" height="29" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M0 28.3h28.3L14.2 0 0 28.3zm5.3-3.2l8.9-17.7L23 25.1H5.3z" />
    </svg>
```

And I want to have this current variant, and also be able to modify it with css to fill it completely; but I cant, even with `fill-rule: nonzero`:

```css
svg {
  fill: black;
  fill-rule: nonzero;
}
```

```html
<svg width="29" height="29" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0 28.3h28.3L14.2 0 0 28.3zm5.3-3.2l8.9-17.7L23 25.1H5.3z" />
</svg>
```

Is there any way to do it?

If it is a problem with the path: how should I create it to be able to fill it completely with css?

Here I add another path I took from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/fill.html#fill-rule) that is working this way:

```css
.path {
  stroke: #000000;
  fill: #6666ff;
}

.path1 {
  fill-rule: nonzero;
}

.path2{
  fill-rule: evenodd;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path class="path path1" d="M50,20 l40,40 l-40,40 l-40,-40 l40,-40 M50,40 l20,20 l-20,20 l-20,-20 l20,-20"
 />
</svg>

<svg>
  <path class="path path2" d="M50,20 l40,40 l-40,40 l-40,-40 l40,-40 M50,40 l20,20 l-20,20 l-20,-20 l20,-20"
 />
</svg>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2yw836rq/?

Comment: It's the way you draw the path. You need to delete part of the d attribute - the part that is drawing the hole. Delete everything from the m: `<path d="M0 28.3h28.3L14.2 0 0 28.3z" />`

Comment: if you use @enxaneta suggestion you can use stroke to have the outside in a different colour if you need.

Comment: @RobertLongson no, because the path wont draw the angles of the triangle

Comment: @enxaneta please read the question, this has nothing to do with the intended result

Comment: We read it. The shape is what it is. You won't be able to fill the centre because the shape has no centre. What do you actually want to draw, because whatever it is you need to accept that you'll need to draw it a different way with different markup.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson; I added a working example with an empty center. I wonder if its the way the path is drawn.

Comment: What do you actually want your drawing to look like? Can we use any markup and CSS we like? If the answer to the second question is no then I think we need to give up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212500/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-emille-c).

Comment: Please try this path: `<path d="M0 28.3h28.3L14.2 0 0 28.3z m5.3-3.2L23 25.1L14.2 7.3z" />` If this is what you want to achieve you need to reverse the second part of the path

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the path. Trying out a different demo and I was able to get fill to work as expected. Try changing the path in your case see if that helps.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 
  <path d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z" fill="black" />
 
   </svg>
```

Comment: No, he's trying to do it using CSS.

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW thanks. Yes, I want to render both options: the path, and the filled triangle.